# Python template matching

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file that contains entries like the following

```
foo: /mnt/scratch-8123/
bar: /mnt/scratch-1512/
```

and I would like to be able write paths like the following in my code:

```
<SCRATCH:foo>/results/stdout.txt
```

The idea is that users can refer to other users' data without having to know where their data is located, since the mapping is maintained by the system.

What would be the cleanest way to recognize such a tag as well as extract the `foo` part of the tag, so that this part of the file path could be replaced by `/mnt/scratch-8123`? I know this can be done with regular expressions, so I'm basically looking for the simplest way to do it...

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this provides a function that takes the string and your list of paths, you'll want to get rid of the trailing slashes on your paths to make things easier.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
def parse(string, paths):
    needed_path = re.findall(r'<SCRATCH:(.*)>', string)[0]
    found_path = re.findall(needed_path+r': (.*)', paths, flags=re.MULTILINE)[0]
    return re.sub(r'<SCRATCH:(.*)>', found_path, string)

print(parse("<SCRATCH:foo>/results/stdout.txt", """
foo: /mnt/scratch-8123
bar: /mnt/scratch-1512
"""))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how well this will match you needs, but a simple method is to use [named placeholders](https://pyformat.info/#named_placeholders) to format the string.

If you parsed the file to a `dict` of the form

```
path_mapping = {'foo': '/mnt/scratch-8123', 'bar': '/mnt/scratch-1512'}
```

> Notice how I've removed the trailing `/` here so that it doesn't occur twice when joined

Then you can construct your strings to be

```
rel_path = '{foo}/results/stdout.txt'
abs_path = rel_path.format(**path_mapping)
# "/mnt/scratch-8123/results/stdout.txt"
```